# Как подключить и настройть php5 на ru-center для joomla 1.7

Tags: joomla, php

Нужно настроить php на ru-center для joomla 1.7. Я не могу подключить php5, выдаёт ошибку, что мне делать и как настроить файл php.ini для joomla и где его разместить.
php уже подключённо и входит в тарифный пакет, но модуль php5 подключатся не хочет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам интересен процесс установки и пошаговой настройки сервера, загляните сюда: [установка Apache + Mysql + Php](http://www.php.ru/install/). Очень полезная информация.

Answer (score 0):

ctype, curl, gd, iconv, json, mbstring, mysql, session, simplexml, timezonedb, zlib
memory_limit=32M
register_globals=off

Answer (score 0):

Ну во первых ошибку в студию, почему то мне кажется что php5 тоже установлен и ссылочку на тарифный план хостинга...